# Why can't I get result list, from a query?

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

I want to login my users only if their account is activated, but for some reason the query that should return me the user (I call it Role in my program) when given the correct credentials, does not retrieve anything at all.

I am 100% sure that the credentials are correct, also I'm sure that there are no duplicates in the database and the query syntax is correct.

So why doesn't this method inside one of my EJBs returns true?:

```
// Checks if the account is not activated!
    public boolean isActivated(String email, String password) {
        // 1-Send query to database to see if that user exist
        Query query = em
                .createQuery("SELECT r FROM Role r WHERE r.email=:emailparam AND r.password=:passwordparam");
        query.setParameter("emailparam", email);
        query.setParameter("passwordparam", password);

        List<Object> tmpList = query.getResultList();
        if (tmpList.isEmpty() == false) {
            System.out.println("IS NOT EMPTY");
            Role role = (Role) tmpList.get(0);
            if (role.getAccountStatus().trim()
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(AccountStattus.ACTIVATED.toString())) {
                // The account is activated!
                System.out.println("ACTIVATED!!!!!!!");
                return true;
            }
        }
        // The account is not activated!
        System.out.println("NOT ACTIVATED!!!!!!!");
        return false;
    }
```

The only message i see in the console is *NOT ACTIVATED!!!!*

**Update**

To comfirm that the list is empty at 100% I modified my code to look like this:

```
// Checks if the account is not activated!
    public boolean isActivated(String email, String password) {
        // 1-Send query to database to see if that user exist
        System.out.println("HERE:" + email+password);
        Query query = em
                .createQuery("SELECT r FROM Role r WHERE r.email=:emailparam AND r.password=:passwordparam");
        query.setParameter("emailparam", email);
        query.setParameter("passwordparam", password);

        List<Object> tmpList = query.getResultList();
        Iterator<Object> it = tmpList.iterator();
        int elements = 0;
        while(it.hasNext()) { 
               elements++;
             }


        if (elements > 0) {
            System.out.println("IS NOT EMPTY");
            Role role = (Role) tmpList.get(0);
            if (role.getAccountStatus().trim()
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(AccountStattus.ACTIVATED.toString())) {
                // The account is activated!
                System.out.println("ACTIVATED!!!!!!!");
                return true;
            }
        }
        // The account is not activated!
        System.out.println("NOT ACTIVATED!!!!!!!");
        return false;
    }
```

The method still returns false when I enter the correct credentials. What is wrong?

Comment: What type is "r FROM Role"? May your query return nothing?

Comment: Did you check which SQL statement is created and did you test that one directly on the DB?

Comment: The name of the table is "Role". The return statement my return nothing, but i am giving good credentials and i don't understand why it does not return true

Comment: @The Elite Gentelman I did what you say but this is what the console says: `Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT * FROM Role r WHERE r.email=:emailparam AND r.password=:passwordparam], line 1, column 7: unexpected token [*].`

Comment: @sfrj, sorry, my mistake. I confused SQL with JPQL. I deleted my comment.

Comment: there is nothing like *. try with this `SELECT r FROM Role  r`

Comment: I am using `r`, i am not using `*` but does not work. I also just checked the credentials(user6 user6), there is just one Row in the DB with those credentials. I don't understand why it does not return true.

Comment: Can you check the generated SQL query ?

Comment: What do you mean by check the generated SQL?, this is how it looks like: `SELECT r FROM Role r WHERE r.email=:emailparam AND r.password=:passwordparam`

Comment: @sfrj: Jigar means the SQL query (not the Hibernate query). There must be a hibernate properties file containing a param: hibernate.show_sql and it should be `hibernate.show_sql=true`. That will print the executed query.

Comment: Anyway I would try removing the "SELECT r" from the query. Simply: `FROM Role r WHERE r.....`

Comment: Hey, just chiming in to remind @sfrj and the rest of the world to never store plain-text passwords. I hope you are doing at least some sort of salt+hash on the password and storing that instead of the password in plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to debug,

1. Run the same query using any SQL client
2. Check your `Role` class. It must have a `email` and `password` properties with appropriate getters/setters

And please don't tell me that the password in the database is a `hashed-version`.

Few basic refactoring suggestions,

1. Write your query in this way to make it easy on eyes,

   ```
   Query query = em.createQuery("from Role r where r.email=:email and r.password=:password")
                   .setParameter("email", email)
                   .setParameter("password", password);
   ```
2. Change your condition to this,

   ```
   if (!list.isEmpty()) {...}
   ```

Comment: I fixed my problem after a bit of debugging. It looks like the password parameter got lost on the way. The query was fine but the credentials wrong when arrived to the EJB. Thank you!

Comment: @sfrj: Glad it worked. But why `password` parameter got lost, and not the `email`? Just curious.

Comment: Nothing special. I use a Managed bean to get the password from the front end and and handle it over. I did some string manipulation to remove blank spaces, but i did not trim() at the end. So the password was wrong. I could not see it was not trimmed in the console since i cannot see blank spaces at the end of the words :)  A bit silly, from me, probably while i was refactoring yesterday i created the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your query list must be empty.  It's either a problem with the database you're connected to (perhaps not the one you think you're tapping), the query, the parameters, or the database.

Comment: Yes the list is empty, that for sure since the condition `if (tmpList.isEmpty() == false)` is not evaluated to true. I am sure at 100% that the database is correct, because i can correctly register users and i see the data inserted in the DB.